# Duda referente a commit masivo con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con php 5 y mysql. Necesito saber la opinión de ustedes respecto a una inserción masiva de registros a una tabla:
Considerando que los datos a ser insertados los tengo en un array, son mayores a 10000 registros y los debo insertar previamente haciendo unas validaciones.
1) Recorro el array, hago la validación e inserto haciendo commit por cada registro

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($array as &$valor) {
// valido datos
$sql = "insert into..";
// commit
}
```

2) Recorro el array, hago la validación, almaceno la sentencia sql en una variable tipo acumulador y ejecuto el commit al final con todas las sentencias almacenadas en el acumulador.

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($array as &$valor) {
// valido datos
$sql = "insert into..";
$acumulador = $acumulador.$sql;
}
//commit
```

Cual sería la opción mas adecuada? o si tienen otra sugerencia desde ya gracias.

Comment: No puedes acumular `INSERT` uno tras otro, pero sí los `VALUES`. Obviamente es mejor hacer todo en una única consulta que en varias, pero también es mejor dividirlo en "trozos" para evitar agotar la memoria disponible para PHP por una consulta SQL excesivamente grande. Los `COMMIT` sólo son necesarios para transacciones en las que necesites que el resultado sea atómico (consistente), cosa que parece que no necesitas en tu código.